# Perform action not just on activity's onCreate but every time view transitions to that activity

Tags: java, android

I am modifying classes based on [this tutorial](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/). I have a Recycler View Activity class with the code something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    checkPastEvents();
}
```

However this function is only called once because since I put it in onCreate() it will only be called when the view is created which is only once. Where can I put this so that whenever I come back to this view, the function is called?

There are several other methods in this Java file i.e.:

```
private class RecyclerViewDemoOnGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) 
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
private void myToggleSelection(int idx) {
```

I'm new to Android development, so let me know if there are some details that are missing from this question and I'll gladly add them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it onResume() which gets called every time the activity is started or resumed (from a paused state)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the method in your onResume method of activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPastEvents(); 
}
```

onResume method will be called whenever your activity becomes visible to user.

And remove the function call from your onCreate.